# about pm2 reloadLogs and log-date-format

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am using pm2 version 0.12.9

I start a app using command:

`pm2 start bin/www --name gototravel --log-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"`

then I query the pm2 logs

`ll ~/.pm2/logs`

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 wucho wucho    0 May 12 11:03 gototravel-error-0.log`

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 wucho wucho 1822 May 12 11:03 gototravel-out-0.log`

my first question is I don't see log file prefixed with a timestamp.

then I run

`pm2 reloadLogs`

and query the pm2 logs,but no another log is generated

`ll ~/.pm2/logs`

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 wucho wucho    0 May 12 11:03 gototravel-error-0.log`

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 wucho wucho 1822 May 12 11:03 gototravel-out-0.log`

I am a nodejs newbee , could you give me any suggestions?

s

Comment: Can you post an example from your code that generates these logs?

Answer (score 0):

`--log-date-format` is a prefix for the entries in the log files, not a prefix for the log file names.

`reloadLogs` doesn't rotate the logs for you. It causes the log file to be recreated if it's been rotated out from under the program by another process.